# ideas on how to build a function in python django for cellulating hours interval

Tags: python, django

I am a total beginner starting a project in Django a payroll calculator app. In it my user has workhours with dates form. The function required should calculate (dates, in hour, out hour) and output the value to another (total hours) field.
the restrictions  are:

1. value must be an integer
2. value can be crossday meaning: giving a worker crossday shift
   07.01.2021,08.01.2021/dates, 22:00:00pm/hour in, 06:00:00am/hour out
3. function must work with Django .models/.datetime

So far I got this code:

```
def HoursTotalConf(in_time, out_time):
    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(in_time, "%H:%M:%S")
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(out_time, "%H:%M:%S")
    return relativedelta(end_dt, start_dt) '
```

Comment: Hey @Dean102. Well done starting up. Stackoverflow is a great place to get answers for particular problems. Expand your post with a certain question and the community will jump in to help. Good luck progressing further.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly do operations with two datetime objects, so if you do `end_dt - start_dt` you will get a timedelta object.

Btw if you are looking to solve the problem within django, instead of using `datetime`, use `timezone` in Django. [django timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/)

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def hours_total_conf(in_time, out_time):
    start_dt = timezone.datetime.strptime(in_time, '%H:%M:%S')
    end_dt = timezone.datetime.strptime(out_time, '%H:%M:%S')
    time_diff = end_dt - start_dt
    # round to hour
    total_hours = round(time_diff.seconds/3600)
    return total_hours
```

---

another thing to mention here is that, if you are solving the problem in Django as explained in restriction 3, why not define these two fields as [datetime fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) so that you don't have to convert it yourself?

Comment: thanks, i understand using timezone but how would i append the value(total_hours) to a "total hours" field?